# Unable to use jQuery

Tags: javascript, ce-1.9.0.1, jquery

Alright, I am trying to do a very simple thing: use jQuery in my `myScript.js` file. I'm on Magento 1.9.0.1. The theme I am building is based on the built-in `rwd` theme, which by default loads jQuery 1.10.2 in *noConflict* mode, locally (as opposed to Google cdn). If I attempt to make a jQuery funtion in `myScript.js`, I get the following error (in my Chrome dev console): **ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined**. However, if I put the same function inside of `<script>` somewhere in the HTML, it works as expected.

So, I have done some researching and poking around and it seems the problem is coming from the load order of `.js` files in the page head, where `myScript.js` is being loaded before `jquery-1.10.2.min.js`. I have tried a lot of different things to fix this (attempting to call `myScript.js` after jQuery)—I have moved the line in `page.xml` that calls jQuery to before the `myScript.js` call. I have moved the `myScript` call to local.xml, where I put it at the very bottom. No matter what I do, I cannot get `myScript.js` to load after `jquery-1.10.2.min.js`. The load order in the `<head>` will always, always be the exact same, regardless of the order I list them in. I can get either file to not load at all by removing it's call from `page.xml`, so I know that I am editing the correct file.

TL;DR: How can I get `myScript.js` to load *after* jQuery?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. Am I using the `backtick markdown` properly in my question? It feels like I am using it really often, but I believe I am following to guidelines. Any stylistic help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer

To force it to load after jQuery in the `head` don't use `addJs`, rather use `<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type>` as skin is loaded after libraries (`addJs`)

### As a side note

1. **My preferred method** of scripting custom jQuery is to add templates to `before_body_end`; there is no `addJs` action for this so instead you'll be creating a template file which includes the script tag with `getSkinUrl`. This ensures that **your script** is non-blocking.  In Magento this may be considered to be laughable (due to the vast number of scripts in `head`) but rather adhere to best practice where your customizations are concerned.
2. Rather than use `jQuery` the RWD framework uses noConflict to alias it to `$j`:

**File: skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/app.js**

```
// ==============================================
// jQuery Init
// ==============================================

// Avoid PrototypeJS conflicts, assign jQuery to $j instead of $
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```