# Product Description Not Appearing. Lower bar not working

Tags: magento-1.9

The lower bar on the `frontend` that contains `description`, `additional information`, and `Reviews` tab is not click-able.

How do I fix this?  As I do not know where to start.

This is what my app.js shows under this heading.

// ==============================================
    // UI Pattern - Toggle Content (tabs and accordions in one setup)
    // ==============================================

```
$j('.toggle-content').each(function () {
    var wrapper = jQuery(this);

    var hasTabs = wrapper.hasClass('tabs');
    var hasAccordion = wrapper.hasClass('accordion');
    var startOpen = wrapper.hasClass('open');

    var dl = wrapper.children('dl:first');
    var dts = dl.children('dt');
    var panes = dl.children('dd');
    var groups = new Array(dts, panes);

    //Create a ul for tabs if necessary.
    if (hasTabs) {
        var ul = jQuery('<ul class="toggle-tabs"></ul>');
        dts.each(function () {
            var dt = jQuery(this);
            var li = jQuery('<li></li>');
            li.html(dt.html());
            ul.append(li);
        });
        ul.insertBefore(dl);
        var lis = ul.children();
        groups.push(lis);
    }

    //Add "last" classes.
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
        groups[i].filter(':last').addClass('last');
    }

    function toggleClasses(clickedItem, group) {
        var index = group.index(clickedItem);
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
            groups[i].removeClass('current');
            groups[i].eq(index).addClass('current');
        }
    }

    //Toggle on tab (dt) click.
    dts.on('click', function (e) {
        //They clicked the current dt to close it. Restore the wrapper to unclicked state.
        if (jQuery(this).hasClass('current') && wrapper.hasClass('accordion-open')) {
            wrapper.removeClass('accordion-open');
        } else {
            //They're clicking something new. Reflect the explicit user interaction.
            wrapper.addClass('accordion-open');
        }
        toggleClasses(jQuery(this), dts);
    });

    //Toggle on tab (li) click.
    if (hasTabs) {
        lis.on('click', function (e) {
            toggleClasses(jQuery(this), lis);
        });
        //Open the first tab.
        lis.eq(0).trigger('click');
    }

    //Open the first accordion if desired.
    if (startOpen) {
        dts.eq(0).trigger('click');
    }

});
```

Comment: Screen shot or link please.

Comment: @Woolfie http://www.retailvariety.com/index.php/2015-malibu-beach-cruiser-electric-bicycle.html

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your javascript. See 'app.js' with this line:

```
dts.on('click', function (e) {
```

On its own that is not much of a clue, however, if you see this question, chances are that you have the same problem - namely that the jQuery library is not being loaded properly with 'no conflict':

[Unable to use jQuery](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30435/unable-to-use-jquery)

Comment: I updated my question with my app.js file where this question is located @woolfie